# Parse Numpy array into 2 arrays - Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, indexing

I am trying to split the values of a numpy array into 2 different new numpy arrays. Heres what the input array (r_array) looks like:

```
['1.50, 2.50' '1.50, 2.50' '1.50, 2.50' '1.50, 2.50' '1.50, 2.50'
 '2.5, 1.00' '2.00, 2.00' '2.00, 5.00' '2, 2' '1.00' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1']
```

You can see it's already been split by ';', now I wish to obtain the strings that have more then one "value" separated by a comma from the strings that only have 1 value.

Heres a snip of the code where i am so far, currently receiving a **IndexError: list index out of range**

```
def split_rates_array(f_path, r_array):
    # parse input array into 2 different arrays
    # array with single rates and array with nth rates
    temp = []
    sin_rate = np.array([])
    dou_rate = np.array([])

    for i in range(len(r_array)):
        for j in range(len(r_array[i])):
            if r_array[i][j] == None:
                continue
            temp[i][j] = r_array[i][j].strip()
            sin_rate = np.append(sin_rate, temp[i][j])

    return sin_rate
```

I know I still need to split the commas, and I also need to account for the length of the single values since errors will raise when trying to access an empty "cell" so I tried to use `continue` to pass the `None` values.

What is the issue with the current code, please and thank you all.

Comment: Your data example is syntactically incorrect. Please fix it.

Comment: Also, please include the complete error message.

Comment: @DYZ how is the data sample incorrect?

Comment: There are missing commas between the strings. If we want to experiment with your code, we would have to type them.